# IBM Websphere Portal authentication methods

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

I am completely ignorant about IBM Websphere, but a sudden integration need forced me to ask this question.

**Background**

We are hosted on AWS and using API Gateway heavily. API gateway currently doesn't supports static IP.
Our client uses IBM Websphere Portal software and currently uses IP whitelisting to give access to the same.

**Problem Statement**
Can we configure both IP whitelisting and Client Certificate both at the same time on IBM websphere and authentication happens based on client request. IP address where ever it is available and certificate otherwise.
The client admin told it is not possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the Infocenter on client certificate authentication

View the steps required to configure IBM® WebSphere® Portal Express® for SSL client certificate authentication. **The supported scenario is a "client certificate only" setup that switches completely to this authentication method and does not allow form-based login via username and password.** Other configuration scenarios are possible, but are neither recommended nor supported.

So once you go to this it is all or nothing

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think I have to find a way to use static IP on AWS.